# Accessing USB webcam hosted on OS X from a Docker container

Tags: macos, docker, usb, webcam

Is it possible to access a USB camera (e.g Logitech c270) from a Docker container?
The camera is connected to a Mac host via a USB port.
Even when running the container with --privileged, i could not find the device (e.g /dev/video0 file does not exist).

Thanks

Comment: What kind of application were you trying to run in the docker container? I'm considering trying to use something to pipe the webcam video into the container or over a network port that the container reads. ffmpeg should be able to do that.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960828/webcam-streaming-from-mac-using-ffmpeg

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015540/capturing-a-multicast-udp-video-stream-using-opencv

http://superuser.com/questions/655378/pipe-webcam-video-stream-data-for-processing

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/can-i-pipe-dev-video-over-ssh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default docker-machine creates a virtual machine with official `boot2docker.iso`. And this slim distro doesn't support USB video device. When you attach the USB device to the virtual machine, the kernel can't do anything without the right driver. So, you won't see any video capturing device, such as `/dev/video0`.

TL;DR

I've compiled a customized [boot2docker.iso](https://github.com/Alexoner/boot2docker/releases/download/v17.06.0-ce-usb-rc5/boot2docker.iso) which ships `uvcvideo` driver. Use this one to create you docker machine.

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url https://github.com/Alexoner/boot2docker/releases/download/v17.06.0-ce-usb-rc5/boot2docker.iso default
```

Then install the VirtualBox extension, attach the webcam device, you are good to go!

Reference

Attach webcam: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#webcam-passthrough